# How can I change the formatting of the mplfinance volume on the chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, finance, mplfinance

I am using mplfinance package to plot candlestick charts of the stock. I am currently trying to figure out how can I change the formatting of the volume in the mplfinance. In all examples provided by the package, and in my own chart the volume comes out in strange notation like 1e23 etc. I would like my volume to reflect the numerical value of what is actually in the pandas dataframe. I trade myself and when I am looking at charts anywhere on the actual trading platforms, it shows normal, it actually shows the volume. But when I look at matplotlib, pandas, mplfinance examples online, the notations is formatted in a strange way everywhere.

[Example of what I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haoWl.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The volume notation is automatically in exponential form based on the size of the volume, so if you want to avoid this, you can avoid it by making the original data smaller with unit data. The following example shows how to deal with this problem by dividing by 1 million. This data is taken from the [official website](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/plot_customizations.ipynb).

```
daily['Volume'] = daily['Volume'] / 1000000
```

This is how we responded.

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd

daily = pd.read_csv('data/SP500_NOV2019_Hist.csv',index_col=0,parse_dates=True)
daily['Volume'] = daily['Volume'] / 1000000

import mplfinance as mpf

mpf.plot(daily,type='candle',volume=True,
         title='\nS&P 500, Nov 2019',
         ylabel='OHLC Candles',
         ylabel_lower='Shares\nTraded')
```

[image]

Example of normal output

[image]

Comment: You have modified the original data by overwriting the column and you have not adjusted the y label to show the new unit. Basically you are offering a solution that shows fake data and removes all traces of the original data, this is not an acceptable answer to me. Also what if you want to create a plotting function to use on many different stocks with different orders of magnitude, how could you make this work without needing to select the correction factor manually for each stock? I will be happy to lift my downvote once you provide a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, to show the volumes ***not*** in scientific notation, but keeping the original values (not scaled down) ... using the same data/code as in the answer from @r-beginners ...

```py
fig, axlist = mpf.plot(daily,type='candle',volume=True,
                       title='\nS&P 500, Nov 2019',
                       ylabel='OHLC Candles',
                       ylabel_lower='Shares\nTraded',
                       returnfig=True)

import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
axlist[2].yaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.FormatStrFormatter('%d'))
mpf.show()
```

The result:
[image]

In theory it would be relatively easy to enhance mplfinance to accept a kwarg for formating the axis labels; but for now the above will work.